# OpenCMS session without cookies?

Tags: java, cookies, opencms

I work on a webpage that is based on OpenCMS and now with the new law in the Netherlands we have to offer an option where we can avoid the JSESSIONID cookie, but I didn't find anything on the web.

Ideas?? Any hints are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

OpenCms templates are plain simple jsp pages. You can disable the session there:

```
<%@ page session="false" language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
```

Comment: THX! This might help, but it doesn't turn off cookies for any case. If openCMS opens a session automatically after my "session false" call it doesn't supress cookies anymore. the question was more if there is an automation to use OpenCMS without cookies on demand?!